# Javascript to get index of all anchor links

Tags: javascript

Jquery version 1.4 supports [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function, but our older environment only supports 1.3, so I can't use .index() until we upgrade later this year.

So, this is my approach at using a mix of traditional javascript with .length and jquery click function to get the index of each anchor when clicked, but my Demo 1 approach returns the total anchors on a page when clicked.

I need your help to make this function extremely simple using onclick (perhaps without an argument) as I need to use it in multiple functions.

```js
$("a").click(function() {
      var links = document.links;
      for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a").length
        alert(link)
        return false;
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>

<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For example, if I had at least 1.4 jQuery I would use this approach and the result in this demo is the expected behavior I'm looking for:

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var count = $(this).index('a');
    alert('link' + count);
    return false;
});
```

Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/43tmut7t/16/

Comment: how about extracting the code inside the newer jquery versions for `index` and implement it as a jquery plugin. that way you can remove it once you update.

Comment: What would that look like? Just looking for a simple solution

Comment: Why do `document.getElementsByTagName("a").length` on every loop? Why not just assign an index to each link as a data- attribute when the page loads (or at the server in the HTML)? *document.links* is a much more efficient way to get all links than *document.getElementsByTagName('a')*.

Comment: something like `$.fn.index = function () { /* implementation from newer jquerys's index method here */ };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're halfway there - just compare each link in the `links` list to `this`:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  var links = document.links;
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i] == this) {
      alert('link ' + i);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="">0</a>
<a href="">1</a>
<a href="">2</a>
<a href="">3</a>
<a href="">4</a>
```

Comment: nice, i just needed if (links[i] == this) instead. That'll work nicely!

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient method is to add a *data-* attribute when the page loads (say *data-linkIndex*), then read the attribute when the link is clicked. It loops over the links once, not every time one is clicked, and reads the value directly off the element, e.g.

```
$(function() {
  for (var links=document.links, i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    links[i].setAttribute('data-linkIndex', i);
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(){console.log(this.getAttribute('data-linkIndex'))});
  }
})
```